# Prometheus sum_over_time only when the value is above a threshold

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I currently use the following query to get the kwh drawn from the grid for this year:

```
sum_over_time( (sum_over_time(wattage_v1[1m])*360/1000/count_over_time(wattage_v1[1m]))[1y:1h] )
```

EDIT: This query seems to deliver basically the same result:

```
sum_over_time(wattage_v1[1y:1h])*360/1000
```

The metric `wattage_v1` provides wattage¹ readings every 15s to 1m.
The query above seems to work. Now I would like to have a similar query which only sums the wattage value if it is above a threshold - say 4000w. I want to roughly estimate the (yearly) consumption of a big consumer that is only running from time to time.

¹ actually 1/360 watt

Thanks

EDIT: I have noticed that the graph doesn't increase monotonic if the range (1y from above set to 1d for example) is smaller than the actual data that is present. I would like to have a counter for the kwh consumed since the beginning of the year or for the selected time range.

Answer (score 1):

The following promql query should return the total energy consumption in [Joules](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) for minutes with over 4kW power usage during the last year ending at the current timestamp:

```
sum_over_time(
  (wattage_v1 > 4000)[1y:1m]
) * 60
```

This query uses [PromQL comparison operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) and [Prometheus subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).

If the result must be converted from `Joules` (aka watt-seconds) to more commonly used kilowatt-hours (aka `kWh`), then it must be divided by 3600000:

```
sum_over_time(
  (wattage_v1 > 4000)[1y:1m]
) * 60 / 3600000
```

P.S. I work on Prometheus-like monitoring system - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/), which provides additional useful functions for energy consumption calculations:

- [integrate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#integrate) is for calculating the [integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) over some metric such as power draw. For example, `integrate(wattage_v1[1y])` would return energy consumption in Joules over the last year ending at the given timestamp.
- [running_sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) is for calculating the [running total](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) over some metric. For example, the following query returns the running total (aka [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter)) of energy consumption in `kWh` over arbitrary time range:

```
running_sum(integrate(wattage_v1)) / 3600000
```

Comment: Thanks, the parentheses at the correct position fixed the 4kw filtering. But setting the range down to a value which is less than the recorded data time range (say 1 week) shows the graph going up and down as well ... Is there another solution than setting a really long time range (100y) and living with enormously big numbers in a few years?


FYI, grouping like that: ```sum(sum_over_time(((wattage_v1*360) > 4000)[$__range:1m])*60/3600000) by (floor)```

Comment: Clarifying: I'd like to use the result of that query to see the consumption for certain time spans/days/months/years. For example: at the 15th Aug the consumption was 12kwh, at the 16th it was 34kwh, ... for all of August it was 123kwh, for September it was 345kwh, ... for 2021 it was 1234kwh, for 2022 it was 5678kwh ... Most comfortably this would be just the time range selected within grafana and start at the beginning of that range with 0kwh, bit fixed ranges would be fine, too